# how to generate unique code for website of many users

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a feature request

1. code is an unique column
2. my users will generate more than 100 codes one request
3. users will generate code at the same time .
4. to code need to random number

I can generate code one by one , but it's not efficient. the problem is many users will use at the same time, I can' generate a bulk insert, the code may conflict.

Is that a bad design ?

by the way , my database is mysql, and I can switch to postgresql

Comment: If you can use UUID as the code, they can be bulk-inserted and will not conflict. The database most likely can generate them server-side, too.

Comment: but my code need to be random number

Comment: A UUID is a random number (just a very long one).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking that you want to insert records 1 - 100 from different users at the same time.  You could write a stored procedure that given a list of string parameters using a transactional insert psuedo code:

data,data2,data3...
begin trans
insert each record into table with unique ID which is an identity (indexed counter)
commit

This might be what you want.

Comment: You can generate a random number based on the user's name + random() function. This may give you what you want. I think you should explain more what you want to accomplish. You can also generate a unique code by using a guid either in sql or in c#. This always generates a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

If you use PostgreSQL and your users ALWAYS will be generating 100 codes, then you can use a simple sequence, and add any two digits after:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE id_template;

-- get 100 new IDs:
SELECT idt + s AS id
FROM (SELECT nextval('serial') * 100 idt) idt, -- takes only one value
     generate_series(0, 99) s; -- adds two digits
```